# Struts2 - Trying to access Session data in setServletResponse()

Tags: struts2

I'm using an action class that implements SessionAware and SerlvetResponseAware.

I'm trying to rewrite the response by using data that I have stored in the Session.

However, when I debug my action class it seems that setServletResponse() is called BEFORE setSession().

Is there another way to do this? Or am I trying to do something wrong?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Hackin time :) I'm pretty sure this is not the way you wanna go to do whatever you are trying to do; post your requirements, let's see the real question

Comment: Just to corroborate the other commentors, you're solution sounds pretty exotic.

Comment: If I try and explain what I'm trying to do, I'll completely expose my lack of knowledge! :-) The intent was to call an action class from a JavaScript function, and have the result of that call be presented in a JavaScript alert() popup. I was able to do a proof-of-concept using text but ultimately wanted to present dynamic data that I had in the session. (Sorry was having editing issues)

Comment: I was using an example I found 'somewhere', and in that example the response was written to in the setServletResponse() method. I assumed that was the correct way to do things. I have now changed the action class to save the HttpServletResponse and then write to it in the execute() method (where I DO have access to my session variables). This seems to work, is this a reasonable approach?